# find difference between max and min element within a range of an array

Tags: c++, algorithm

Say I got following array

```
a = [4 5 2 1 3 4]
```

and I want to find the  difference between two elements (the max and min) excluding some consecutive elements.

For example, excluding the 2nd and 3rd so that I need to find the difference of max/min of:

```
  a = [4 1 3 4]
```

which in this case is

```
 diff = 4-1
```

Now I am looking for an efficient algorithm that can do this over and over.
I was considering having a prefix and suffix but not sure how to move forward

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So we have an array `a` of size `N` and `M` queries of this form: "Excluding the interval [L, R], what's the difference between the max and min element in `a`?". Consider we have an efficient way to query the min and max value on an arbitrary interval `[X, Y]`, then we can use the following algorithm:

1. Query min/max on the interval `[0, L)`
2. Query min/max on the interval `(R, N)`
3. Combine the min and max from both intervals
4. Subtract the two

**Later edit:** I initially proposed a solution much more complicated than necessary. I will leave it if you are curious about other approaches, but here it is a simpler one.

As we know that we will always query only intervals of form `[0, something)` and `(something, N)`, we could precompute the min/max values in linear time. Consider storing them like this:

```
min_from_left[i] = minimum item considering only items 0..i
min_from_right[i] = minimum item considering only items i..N
same for max
```

Now, the minimum value excluding the interval `[L, R]` is `min(min_from_left[L-1], min_from_right[R+1])` (I omitted the bound checks). Thus, you can achieve `O(N)` for precomputing and `O(1)` per query.

**The generic (but unnecessary approach)**

To find the min/max value in a given interval you have plenty of options, it just depends what are your time and memory constraints and if you need updates or not:

- [Segment trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_tree) (support updates)
- [Sparse tables](https://cp-algorithms.com/sequences/rmq.html) (does not support updates)

Generally, you can obtain `O(N + M * log N)` time complexity if you need updates or `O(N log N + M)` if you don't need them.

See more options here https://cp-algorithms.com/sequences/rmq.html

Comment: Would a combination of prefix  and suffix not help to quert the min/max in intervals

Comment: I don't really understand your question. Could you rephrase?

Comment: I am talking in relation to finding the min/max of the two different intervals. I wonder if I could use some sort of prefix/suffix to be able to find the min/max

Comment: Hmmm, I think you could. I will make an edit to my answer

Comment: [std::minmax](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax)

Comment: @Eljay std::minmax has `O(N)` complexity, so you will get a total complexity of `O(N*M)` and I wouldn't call this "efficient".

Answer (score 1):

Just scan the array. Store min and max values while ignoring ones that are excluded.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int arr[6] = { 4, 5, 2, 1, 3, 4 };
    int max = arr[0], min = arr[0];
    int first, second;
    cout << "Enter Range (first value): ";
    cin >> first; // in your example, first = 1 
    cout << "Enter Range (last value): ";
    cin >> second; // second = 2, in your example. 

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        if (i >= first && i <= second)
            continue;
        if (arr[i] < min)
            min = arr[i];
        if (arr[i] > max)
            max = arr[i];
    }
    cout << "Difference between max and min is " << max - min << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No because as mentioned this needs to be run over the same array many times with different `first` and `second`, although the difference  of the latter will always be the same. One example is having an array with 1000000 elements and you need to find the optimal section which minimizes the difference between max and min given a constant number of exclusions .